# Are function declarations and function expressions implemented differently in Go? If yes, why?

Tags: function, go, language-implementation

I just got into programming again with Go (with no experience whatsoever in low-level languages), and I noticed that function expressions are not treated the same as function declarations (`go1.18.5 linux/amd64`).

For instance, this works (obviously):

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
  fmt.Println("Do stuff")
}
```

But this outputs an error:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

var main = func() {
  fmt.Println("Do stuff")
}
```

```
./prog.go:3:8: imported and not used: "fmt"
./prog.go:5:5: cannot declare main - must be func

Go build failed.
```

Even specifying the type as in `var main func() = func() {}` does nothing for the end result. Go seems to, first of all, evaluate if the `main` identifier is being used in any declaration, ignoring the type. Meanwhile, Javascript folks seem to choose what is more readable, like there's no underlying difference between them.

Questions:

- Are function declarations and function expressions implemented differently under the hood, or is this behavior just hard-coded?
- If yes, is the difference between these implementations critical?
- Is Go somewhat better in any way for doing it the way it does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the spec](https://go.dev/ref/spec):

> The main package must [...] declare a function `main` that takes no arguments and returns no value.

The moment you write `var main` you prevent the above requirement from being met, because what you are creating is a variable storing a **reference to a function literal** as opposed to *being* a **function declaration**.

> A function declaration binds an identifier, the function name, to a function.

> A function literal represents an anonymous function.

So:

> Are function declarations and function expressions implemented differently under the hood?

Yes.

> Is Go somewhat better in any way for doing it the way it does?

Generally, no. It comes with the territory of being a typed language, which has all sorts of pros and cons depending on use.

> If yes, is the difference between these implementations critical?

By what standard? As an example, a variable referencing a function literal could be `nil`, which isn't usually something you'd like to call. The same cannot happen with function declarations (assuming package `unsafe` is not used).

Comment: "_A variable referencing a function literal could be nil. The same cannot happen with function declarations_". That's an important fundamental difference to know. The question was about the difference between javascript and go, though, but you also answered it with "_It comes with the territory of being a typed language_".

Answer (score 2):

The code

```
func main() {
  fmt.Println("Do stuff")
}
```

binds a function to the identifier `main`.

The code

```
var main = func() {
  fmt.Println("Do stuff")
}
```

binds a variable of type `func ()` to the identifier `main` and initializes the variable to the result of a function expression.

> Are function declarations and function expressions implemented differently under the hood, or is this behavior just hard-coded?

A function expression evaluates to a function value. A function declaration binds a function value to a name. There is no difference in the implementation of these function *values* (but the result of an expressions can additionally close over function scoped variables).

> If yes, is the difference between these implementations critical?

Yes.

- The question points out one scenario where the difference is important (program execution starts at the function `main` in package `main`)
- The compiler cannot inline a function called through a variable.
- Functions cannot be declared inside another function, but a function expression can be assigned to a variable in a function.

> Is Go somewhat better in any way for doing it the way it does?

Other languages make a distinction between an identifier bound a function and and identifier bound to a variable with a function type. Go is no better or worse in than those languages with regards to the binding of identifiers.

The OP [says in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73587093/are-function-declarations-and-function-expressions-implemented-differently-in-go/73587296#comment129948138_73587311):

> The question was about the difference between javascript and go, though, but you also answered it with "It comes with the territory of being a typed language".

The difference is unrelated to being a typed language. Identifiers can be bound to constants, types, variables and functions in Go.  I may be going out on a limb here, but non-reserved identifiers in Javascript are always bound to variables.